# Initialization Vector on Cryptography

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, initialization-vector

I have a question regarding how initialization vector works on cryptography.

I have bit of knowledge about creating a IV and my question would be this,
I know about [SecureRandom](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) class so once I create a IV through this it will perfectly encrypt the data, what I don't understand is how can you get the same IV for the decryption process? (Please explain I need to know about this to create an algorithm for a assignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the IV is sent along with the ciphertext in network protocols, or stored somewhere along with the ciphertext, e.g. at the beginning of the file in a file encryption scheme.  For block ciphers in CBC mode, it is very common to simply send or store the IV as first ciphertext block.  The IV is not a secret, but depending on your cryptosystem, it should not be reused or be predictable.

Comment: When you say it shouldn't be predictable does that means that the way of generating IV shouldn't be preditable??
And is it okay to just append the IV (like a plaintext) since IV is not a secret??

Comment: Yes, appending the IV is okay, but not like a plaintext but like a ciphertext.  If you append the IV to the plaintext before encrypting, you will send the IV encrypted (which is impossible to decrypt without knowing the IV in the first place). Saying the IV should not be predictable is roughly the same as saying the IV should be generated randomly. There are some attacks which only work if the attacker knows the IV beforehand, to be able to choose a specific plaintext. An example is a chosen-plaintext attack on CBC (which was the basis of the recent BEAST attack on SSL).